# How do I increase the RPi 3 minimum clock speed without using force_turbo?

Tags: pi-3, cpu, overclocking

So I don't want to change my max clock speed, but I want to slightly increase the minimum clock speed at light load from 600MHz to 800MHz. However, if I set these options in my `/boot/config.txt/` and check `lscpu`, the minimum frequency doesn't change. How do I change the minimum frequency without enabling `force_turbo` if possible?

```
arm_freq=1200
arm_freq_min=800
```

Comment: After the change, did you a reboot? And the check the freq, use `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_mix_freq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower frequency arm_freq_min cannot be adjusted above the stock value.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28310#p250842

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md

Comment: Ah thats unfortunate. I guess using force_turbo is the only option for now.